# Книга по C++

Tags: книги, c++

Помогите вспомнить книгу по C++.

Вчера на чужом компе в инете нарыл хорошую книгу по C++. На своем весь день найти не могу.
Не помню ни названия, ни автора. Только помню то, что в ней больше 1100 страниц и глава "Учимся программировать на C++" начинается с 52 страницы =/

Comment: А может глава: "Приступаем к программированию на C++" и и страниц 1171?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Книги и другая литература по С++](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454263/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%83%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%a1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Книга "Стивен Парта. Язык программирования C++" 1171 страница на 52 странице есть глава "Приступаем к программированию на C++" и вообще очень классная книга я сам её счас читаю...

Comment: ОНА! Спасибо!

Comment: Не за что! Я тоже считаю что эта книга THE BEST :)

Answer (score 1):

Судя по тому, что книга хорошая, может быть это Страуструп (страниц в некоторых изданиях примерно столько же)

Правда нет дословно такой главы "Учимся программировать на c++"

Даже если книга не та, все равно она хороша :)

Comment: почитаю. Спс.

Comment: Да ну, у Страуструпа бессмысленно читать что-либо, кроме [`The Design and Evolution of C++`][1]. Хваленый `The C++ Programming Language` хуже подходит для новичков, чем любая книга из разряда `C++ Primer`, но в то же время не дотягивает до уровня остальной литературы из разряда `C++ in depth`.

[1]: http://www.amazon.com/The-Design-Evolution-Bjarne-Stroustrup/dp/0201543303